# NoMethodError after integrating google-api-client 0.9.pre3 in dashing

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-analytics-api, dashing

I installed shopify dashing on my localhost and it is working fine prior to google client api installation but after doing bundle for google-api-client version 0.9.pre3 it is showing error as in attached images.
For rectifying this issue I installed dashing but unable to find the resolve this issue.

[image: front-end of dashing after doing bundle of google-api-client version 0.9.pre3]

[image: terminal screenshot after doing dashing start]

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/581, it may be related

Comment: That literally means that it's not defined as a method

Comment: I already tried that method and installed fresh dashing but unable to rectify problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your install of dashing is out of date. Mine is at 1.3.4 but I was getting this error when I installed.

```
gem update dashing
```

should do the trick. Once I'd updated dashing some of the other gems needed updating as well.
Not sure why the default install is an earlier version. I'm on Win7 with Ruby 2.0.0p647

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with your dependencies, you haven't correctly installed them into your environment somehow. Make sure you're following the getting started instructions on the website:

http://dashing.io/#setup

Comment: I already rectified this issue. There was a problem with version of dependencies. Dashing needs older version of some dependencies.

Comment: @hmjha what did you have to do to the dependencies to resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: check the necessary version of some dependencies like Thor. There may be latest version of dependencies by default but Dashing needs older one, so you have to install old version. Remember one thing is that don't uninstall newer one also because anyone else can use it.